# Can I make an ngFor repeath specifict times of an array? Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngfor, infinite-scroll, ion-list

I have an ion-list that shows n objects of an array.
I'm using *ngFor to show them.
The problem is that the array will have n quantity of objects.It could be 10 objects or 2000. I would like to show the first 30 objects, then, use an infinite scroll and show the next 30.
How could I do it? This is my code:

```
    <div *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(message)">
      <ion-card class="{{val.Status}}" *ngFor="let val of message[key]"> 
        <ion-card-header class="headerClass">
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col size="11"><ion-label class="titulo">{{val.Permiso}}</ion-label></ion-col>
            <ion-col *ngIf="val?.Status == 'Autorizado'" size="1" ><ion-icon color="success" style="zoom:1.5;" name="checkmark-circle-outline"></ion-icon></ion-col>
            <ion-col *ngIf="val?.Status == 'Rechazado'" size="1"><ion-icon color="danger" style="zoom:1.5;" name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon></ion-col>
            <ion-col *ngIf="val?.Status == 'Pendiente'" size="1"><ion-icon color="warning" style="zoom:1.5;" name="help-circle-outline"></ion-icon></ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-card-header> 
        <ion-card-content>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col size="12" ><b>Fecha de inicio: </b> {{val.FechaInicio | date: 'd/M/yyyy'}}</ion-col>
          </ion-row>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col *ngIf="val?.FechaFin != null" size="12" ><b>Fecha de termino: </b> {{val.FechaFin | date: 'd/M/yyyy'}}</ion-col>
          </ion-row>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col size="6"><b>Hora de inicio:</b> {{val.HoraInicio}}</ion-col>
            <ion-col  size="6"><b>Hora termino:</b> {{val.HoraFin}}</ion-col>
          </ion-row>
          <ion-row *ngIf="val?.FechaReanudacion != null">
            <ion-col size="12" ><b>Fecha reanudacion: </b> {{val.FechaReanudacion | date: 'd/M/yyyy'}}</ion-col>
          </ion-row>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col *ngIf="val?.Status == 'Rechazado'"  size="12" ><b>Motivo:</b> {{val.Comentarios}}</ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </div>
  </div> 

This is how a fill my array: 

MisPermisos(datos){  
    this.proveedor.MostrarPermisos(datos).subscribe(
      async (dataReturnFromService2)=>{
        this.dataFromService2 = (dataReturnFromService2);
        let obj2 = JSON.parse(this.dataFromService2);
        if((dataReturnFromService2) == '{"Table":[]}'){
          this.noHayPermisos();
        }
        else{
          this.messages = [obj2] ;
          this.keys = Object.keys([obj2]);
          this.prueba = (obj2.Table[0].Status);  
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation on it? https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/infinite-scroll

Comment: @Super_Simon hey I'm not sure if I can ask this here, but I was wondering why didn't you post it as an answer instead of comment? to me it seems like it's exactly what they need and it's not mentioned in the question at all.

Comment: A fair point but frankly I don't think it's answer-worthy. Yes, it answers the question here, but seeking out and reading the documentation is a basic step in the development lifecycle process. Personally I believe an answer is reserved for when you want to provide context and examples to a specific question and not for copying and pasting a link which would directly answer the question.